# Starfield of Nyx and Eerie Interlude

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Say you have 7 enchantments on the field, including two [Starfield of Nyx](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Starfield%20of%20Nyx) and a creature that cares about creatures entering the battlefield (e.g.[Soul Warden](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Soul%20Warden)). You cast [Eerie Interlude](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Eerie%20Interlude) targeting some number of the enchantment creatures to flicker them.

I know that if you flicker 1 enchantment creature, it'll trigger Soul Warden once.

1. If you flicker the two Starfield of Nyx, will they enter as creatures?
2. If you flicker three non-Starfield enchantment creatures, will they re-enter as creatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The enchantment creatures you flickered will enter the battlefield as enchantment creatures in both cases.**

The static ability of Starfield of Nyx creates a continuous, type-changing effect. As such, it works as soon as the permanent it changes enters the battlefield. As long as the condition is fulfilled, enchantments including themselves enter the battlefield as creatures and trigger Soul Warden.

Note that Soul Warden would be triggered even if Starfield's condition is only fulfilled with their own presence, e.g. if you flicker the 2 Starfields and control only 3 other enchantments.

> 603.6b Continuous effects that modify characteristics of a permanent do so the moment the permanent is on the battlefield (and not before then). The permanent is never on the battlefield with its unmodified characteristics. [..]

Comment: I don't think this is correct. Consider this ruling on [Thassa, God of the Sea](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373535): "9/15/2013 If a God enters the battlefield, your devotion to its color (including the mana symbols in the mana cost of the God itself) will determine if a creature entered the battlefield or not, for abilities that trigger whenever a creature enters the battlefield."

Comment: Nevermind. That ruling actually supports your answer, and I just misread it.